# bootstrap grid with stacked columns

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing bootstrap grid and i want `internal` columns to stack on mobile device.

Also the `.col-xs-4` should take full height but it doesn't

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-4 left-col wrap">.col-xs-4<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 top-col no-padding">
        <div class="row no-margin">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 child-col">internal<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 child-col">internalbr>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 child-col">internal<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 child-col">internal<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 child-col">internal<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 child-col">internal<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 middle-col">.col-xs-5<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 bottom-col no-padding">
        <div class="col-xs-2 child-col">internal<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 child-col">internal<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 child-col">internal<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 child-col">internal<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 child-col">internal<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 child-col">internal<br>Subsequent columns continue along the new line.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/12117/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `col-xs-2` to `col-xs-12` for all the internal columns. Basically, in Bootstrap, size "12" is all  12 of the avaialble cols a page can have. When your website goes to a mobile screen, bootstrap css will automatically apply the `col-xs-12` to do what you want.

Comment: that worked thanks but my left column still doesnt seem to stretch to full height of 'container-fluid' div

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're talking about, container-fluid divs do not have a fixed height, so even if you set the height of "left column" (which I'm assuming is the col-xs-4 one) to 100%, it won't do anything.